# Toggle Visibility of Container in adaptive card based on input choice set value

Tags: json, power-automate, adaptive-cards, power-virtual-agents

I have tried using multiple ways to toggle the visibility of date_selection_container but nothing works. I want to toggle the visibility if the Date Wise Leave is selected and user should see two input date box

```
isVisible": "=if(equals(triggerOutputs['feature_choice']['value'], 'Date Wise Leave'), true, false)"
```

and

```
conditions": [
            {
                "type": "Equals",
                "left": "${feature_choice.value}",
                "right": "Date Wise Leave"
            }
        ]
```

and

```
"isVisible": "=contains(triggerOutputs['feature_choice']['value'], 'Date Wise Leave')"
```

Code

```
{
            "type": "Input.ChoiceSet",
            "id": "feature_choice",
            "label": "Which type of leave information you needed?",
            "placeholder": "Please Select the feature type",
            "value": "Monthly Leave",
            "choices": [
                {
                    "title": "Monthly Leave",
                    "value": "Monthly Leave"
                },
                {
                    "title": "Date Wise Leave",
                    "value": "Date Wise Leave"
                },
                {
                    "title": "Recent 5 Leave",
                    "value": "Recent 5 Leave"
                }
            ],
            "isRequired": true,
            "wrap": true,
            "separator": true
        },
        {
            "type": "Container",
            "id": "date_selection_container",
            "padding": "None",
            "when": "${feature_choice.value == 'Date Wise Leave'}",
            "items": [
                {
                    "type": "Input.Date",
                    "label": "From",
                    "id": "start_date_input"
                },
                {
                    "type": "Input.Date",
                    "label": "To",
                    "id": "end_date_input",
                    "value": "2023-04-27"
                }
            ]
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think this is possible at the moment, it's a feature that's been requested for years.

https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/msteams-docs/issues/7164